# VIRTUALBOX INSTALLATION - 'modprobe vboxdrv failed' after trying to rebuild kernel modules

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I Have been trying to follow this guide: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ on how to install VirtualBox 5.2 on Fedora 27. It all went pretty smooth until I used the command '/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup' to rebuild the kernel modules. Below you can see that the problem lies on the last line:

```
 # /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

`vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed.` makes it seem like there is some error. Does anybody know how to fix this and correctly finish the installation and everything?

I have been trying to install VirtualBox on Fedoracorrectly so that I don't get the well-known error rc=-1908 when I try to launch an OS in VirtualBox.

Comment: `Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.`

Answer (score 1):

Since the questioner only provided little useful information (no kernel version, no log file / dmesg, ...) I can only ask my cloudy crystal ball here.

It says: Since the installation of VirtualBox 5.2 on Fedora 27 is usually painless (and since the guides from If-not-true-than-false are usually fine), "Secure Boot" might be enabled in the UEFI/BIOS and is preventing the vboxdrv driver from loading.